# Error installing wine

Tags: wine, software-center, internet, sudo

When I install wine, I get this. I have ubuntu 13.10. I am connected to the internet, I am posting this with the same computer. I have no proxy.

**Fixed. I the source to the Main not US**

```
ben@ben-HP-ENVY-dv4-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  liblcms2-2:i386 winbind wine-gecko2.24 wine-gecko2.24:i386 wine-mono4.5.2
  wine1.7-amd64 wine1.7-i386:i386 winetricks
Suggested packages:
  liblcms2-utils:i386 libpam-winbind libnss-winbind dosbox:any
Recommended packages:
  wine1.5-amd64 wine1.5-i386:i386 wine-mono4.5.2:i386 wine1.5 wine1.4 wine
  cxoffice5 cxgames5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  liblcms2-2:i386 winbind wine-gecko2.24 wine-gecko2.24:i386 wine-mono4.5.2
  wine1.7 wine1.7-amd64 wine1.7-i386:i386 winetricks
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,511 kB/156 MB of archives.
After this operation, 378 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  liblcms2-2
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main winbind amd64 2:3.6.18-1ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main winbind amd64 2:3.6.18-1ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/winbind_3.6.18-1ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

When I do it through the software center, I get this.
[image: Software Center Error]

Comment: terminal is the only way.Check you have properly disabled your proxy by changing the proxy method to none in network.

Comment: Where do I do that? Sorry I'm new to ubuntu

Comment: search for network in dash.

Comment: I did unset HTTP_PROXY and still no difference

Comment: http://gyazo.com/931819e270ed1ead33a191e418bee741 proxy is off

Comment: Choose best server in software and updates.And then do, `sudo apt-get update`.Finally run the above command.

Comment: I changed to the Main Server and it seems to be working. Thanks

Comment: 1) Are you sure you want to install `wine1.7` and not `wine`. I don't seem to find any package called `wine1.7`. 2) Can you reset your software sources and update and try again?

Comment: @Jobin I followed this http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu

Comment: You are actually installing [a beta version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Stages_of_development) of wine, are you sure you want to do this? If yes, why. If you just want wine to be installed you can just do `sudo apt-get install wine`.

Comment: Oh okay @Jobin thanks. btw it worked thanks I changed it to US

Comment: Can you please post the solution as an answer so that people who come up to this post would benefit?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the US servers were down, so what I did was I went to the software center and did Edit > Software Sources.

Then I changed it from US to Main